# Multiple loops in apps script

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, google-apps-script, google-slides

I am trying to run a replace text function on my slides based on an two arrays; the first array is the values that are to be replaced and the second array are the values that the corresponding values in the first array should be replaced with.

I.e. the first value in the first array should be replaced by the first value in the second array.

This is my attempt at doing it

```
function myFunction() {
var currentPresentationSlide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides();
var array1 = ['{{remove}}','{{remove2}}','{{remove3}}'];
var array2 = ['new value','new value2','new value 3'];
for (i = 0, s = 0, x = 0; i < currentPresentationSlide.length, s < array1.length, x < array2.length; i++, s++, x++) {
currentPresentationSlide[i].replaceAllText(array1[s],array2[x])
 }
}
```

What further complicates it is, that the replaceAllText will only run on a single page and not the entire presentation, hence it will have to be run as a loop on each individual page in the slide (which is the reason for the loop with the i variable.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, cause this is not working for me

Comment: You probably want to && the conditions. Separating them with a comma will ignore the answers to the first two. You also need to loop over the arrays indepdendently of looping over the slides, so you'll need two nested for loops. (i.e. at the moment you're only looking for substitution 1 on slide 1, substitution 2 on slide 2 and sub 3 on slide 3, then stopping.) And you can use the same variable to index both arrays.

Comment: Thanks Rup - I found a solution because of your answer - much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Rup in the comments i solved it. Just in case anyone has the same issue this is my solution:

```
function myFunction() {
var currentPresentationSlide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides();
  var array1 = ['{{remove}}','{{remove2}}','{{remove3}}'];
  var array2 = ['new value','new value 2','new value 3'];
  for (i = 0; i < currentPresentationSlide.length; i++) {
    for (s = 0; s < array1.length; s++)
currentPresentationSlide[i].replaceAllText(array1[s],array2[s])
 }
}
```